# What values are acceptable for the dispersion parameter in GLMM with Poisson distribution on count data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, glmm, biostatistics

I'm investigating the effect of three factors (day of observation, parity, gestation) on the number of various behaviors in pigs. For this, I'm using GLMM with a Poisson distribution and logarithm as a link function. I'm using the duration of observation as the offset. My dataset is extremely positively skewed with loads of zeros. The issue is that also my dataset is not well-balanced for these factors (because it was not the main aim of the study). Because of this and the high number of zeros, my model fails to run (fixed model: day of observation, parity, gestation; random model: Group ID/pig ID). On top of that, I'm getting dispersion parameters ranging from 0.2 to 3.

So, my question is, given the nature of my dataset, how flexible can I be with the dispersion parameter? I know it should be 1 for GLMM...

**Additional info**: The high number of zeros in my dataset is due to the nature of the behaviours I'm studying. These behaviours are quite rare. So, the zero mean that the pig was not doing a specific behaviour at the moment I was observing it.

Comment: Why the many zeros? Maybe look into zero-inflation ...

Comment: Hi @kjetilbhalvorsen I've updated my question to answer to your question. I hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have important overdispersion or underdispersion, a quick fix could be to use a negative binomial distribution for your model instead of a Poisson distribution. This distribution has an extra parameter to handle dispersion unlike the Poisson distribution. Another possibility if you want to stay with the Poisson distribution is to add a random intercept at the level of the observations as described below.

$$Y \sim Poisson(\lambda)$$
$$log(\lambda_i) = X\beta + \nu_i$$
$$\nu_i \sim Normal(0,\sigma)$$

A more formal presentation can be found here : https://peerj.com/articles/616/

However, I suggest to try the negative binomial model, the observation level random effect can be difficult to estimate, especially if you have other random effects in your model

Comment: Thanks, Jérémy! I will check this.

Comment: It is a pleasure, if you think that the answer is helpful, do not forget to upvote or/and mark it as accepted answer, it will be appreciated! Good luck with your analysis

Comment: Hi Jérémy! I just wanted to say that changing the distribution to negative binomial worked pretty well, with only one variable going a bit underdispersed (0.5). I asked aroung and they said this was acceptable :) All the best.

Comment: great, thank you for sharing your experience!